# Google Analytics - Spam Data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, spam

I have an issue in which I'm receiving bad data from Analytics. In a report where the Page Title is the primary dimension, there are 2 Page Titles in my data that are not a part of my site.

The names (sharebutton.org/eu-cookie-law.info) and activity (0 avg. time on page) make it clearly look like Spam. What's odd is that I never added the tracking code to any other place than my own site.

Any ideas on the issue?
Or what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to filter them out using a hostname filter.

Select Hostname as a secondary dimension to check what the hostname is - probably it isn't your hostname and is a fake/spammy one.

Use [this guide](https://www.ohow.co/ultimate-guide-to-removing-irrelevant-traffic-in-google-analytics/) to create a filter to included only your valid (actual) Hostnames in your analytics data.